# Excel - How to subtract a Fixed number from each cell separately and then sum the results in one cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Am trying to subtract a fixed number from all cells in column separately, and then sum the result in one cell, i want all this function in one cell, its easy to do it each one alone but i want to mix it in one cell.

here is my example: I want my fixed number (300) to be subtracted from each cell in column **A** and then sum the results from them in one cell (**B1**) = 30

```
        **A**               **B**

**1**    200                  30

**2**    300

**3**    70

**4**    100

**5**    500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know exact formula, you can use math:

```
300-A1+300-A2+300-A3+300-A4=300+300+300+300-A1-A2-A3-A4=
=300*4-(A1+A2+A3+A4)=300*COUNT(A1:A4)-SUM(A1:A4)
```

Comment: Thank you , this is what am looking for !! the COUNT function !!

Answer (score 1):

try this in B1,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(300-A1:A4)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the problem is that with SUMPRODUCT am not getting the results that i want. For example if i input in cell (A5) 500 i should get the result in B 30 , this is what i want exactly, and i want it to work on all cells  in column as well , when am trying to extend it on whole column am getting really huge value because SUMPRODUCT is multiplying something